# How do I set all options of my quiz to active: false on click?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to build a question (eventually a quiz) with multiple choice options.  When a user click's on an option the active class is set to true and a red background is inserted for the option.  What I'd like help with is if the user decides to click another option.  The previously active option should be changed to active: false and the new option should change to active: true.  This is my first Ember.js application so if there's a better way to do this I'm all ears.

```
 var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return Ember.A([
      {
        question: "What's up?",
        options: [
          {
            text: "option a",
            active: false
          },
          {
            text: "option b",
            active: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: "How many?",
        options: [
          "one",
          "two"
        ]
      }
     ]);
   }
 });
```

index.hbs

```
{{#each model}}
  {{quiz-question section=this}}
{{/each}}
```

quiz-question.hbs

```
{{#with section}}
  {{question}}
  {{#each options}}
    {{quiz-option active=active text=text}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}

{{yield}}
```

quiz-option.hbs

```
<div {{bind-attr class="active"}}>{{text}}</div>

{{yield}}
```

quiz-option.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function () {
    console.log('asdf', this.get('text'));
    this.set('active', true);
  }
});
```

app.css

```
html, body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sendAction` to pass an action out to a parent level where it can iterate the collection and set all of the other items to false.

```
App.QuizOptionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function () {
    this.set('active', true);
    this.sendAction('killFriendsExcept', this.get('text'));
  }
});

{quiz-option active=active text=text  killFriendsExcept='resetChildrenExcept'}}


App.QuizQuestionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    resetChildrenExcept: function(except){
      this.get('section.options').forEach(function(item){
        if(Em.get(item, 'text')!=except){
          Em.set(item, 'active', false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jitezago/1/edit

Comment: This works great kingpin.  I changed your !=except to strict comparison !== except, added a curly bracket to {{quiz-option, and changed this.set('active', true) to this.toggleProperty('active', true).  The toggle is just in case the user clicks on the same option twice to unselect it.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also changed Em.get/Em.set to Ember.get/Ember.set for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I get lazy sometimes.  There is definitely room for improvement

Comment: Hey kingpin.  I posted another stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040091/why-cant-i-set-this-object-property) that's somewhat related to this one.  Since you're obviously knowledgeable on this subject could you take a look?